# Complex vector fields on $2n$-dimensional smooth manifolds: Worked out example.

Tags: complex-geometry

I am really struggling with the notion of complex vector field on a $2n$-dimensional smooth manifold and I am hoping to work out a down-to-earth example. I am very confused so the questions might be a bit wacky.

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ with global coordinates $(x_1, x_2)$.

*What does a complex vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ look like?*

For example, let $z=x_1 + i x_2$, then,

(1) Is a complex vector field on $\mathbb{R}^2$ generated by $\partial_z$ OR $\{\partial_z, \partial_{\overline{z}} \}$?

(2) Are the coefficients on $\partial_z$ (or, possibly, $\{\partial_z, \partial_{\overline{z}} \}$) smooth functions in $(x_1,x_2)$ of holomorphic functions in $z$, or just some function in $(z, \overline{z})$?

Comment: By _complex vector field_ do you mean a smooth section of the complexified tangent bundle, a smooth section of the $(1, 0)$ part of the complexified tangent bundle, something else...?

Comment: It probably means a smooth section of the $(1,0)$ part of the complexified tangent bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$I'll write $x_{1} = x$ and $x_{2} = y$ (so $z = x + iy$), since this tends to simplify notation in higher complex dimension.

Over the smooth, complex-valued functions, the complexified tangent bundle of $\Reals^{2}$ is spanned by
$$
\frac{\dd}{\dd x},\quad
\frac{\dd}{\dd y},\quad
i \frac{\dd}{\dd x},\quad
i \frac{\dd}{\dd y}.
$$
The $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ parts are respectively spanned by
$$
\frac{\dd}{\dd z} = \frac{1}{2}\biggl[\frac{\dd}{\dd x} - i \frac{\dd}{\dd y}\biggr],\qquad
\frac{\dd}{\dd \bar{z}} = \frac{1}{2}\biggl[\frac{\dd}{\dd x} + i \frac{\dd}{\dd y}\biggr].
$$
A complex vector field, i.e., smooth section of the $(1, 0)$ part, may therefore be written
$$
2f(x, y)\dfrac{\dd}{\dd z}
= f(x, y) \biggl[\frac{\dd}{\dd x} - i \frac{\dd}{\dd y}\biggr]
$$
for some smooth, complex-valued function $f$.

Comment: Smooth sections of them are, yes. (E.g., a holomorphic vector field would be a holomorphic function times $\partial/\partial z$.)